# SOSL Query and Update

Tags: apex, query, update, sosl

I am practicing SOSL queries. I tried to find the matching records of given Email ID across all objects and update it to new Email ID using SOSL query.

My Code:

```
public class Soslxmpl{
    public List<List<Sobject>> updateEmail(){
        String emailid = 'richie@gmail.com';
        List<List<SObject>> Sobj = [FIND 'richie@gmail.com' 
                                    IN email Fields
                                    Returning 
                                    Case(CaseNumber,SuppliedEmail),
                                    Candidate__C(Name,Email_Id__c),
                                    Contact(Name),
                                    Lead(Name)];
        Case[] cases = (Case[])Sobj[0];
        Candidate__C[] cand = (Candidate__C[])Sobj[1];
        Contact[] cont = (Contact[])Sobj[2];
        Lead[] leads = (Lead[])Sobj[3];
        for(Case Casse : Cases)        
        {
            Casse.SuppliedEmail= emailid;
        }
        for(Candidate__C Candi : cand)
        {
            Candi.Email_Id__C = emailid;
        }
        For(Contact con : Cont)
        {
            con.Email = emailid;
        }
        return Sobj;
        update Sobj;
    } }
```

I don't know how to update generic objects.Please help me to update email with new mail id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options for the DML. Single DML calls to each collection of `SObject` type, Single DML call to a grouped collection of `SObject` types.

For single DML calls to each collection of `SObject` type, as you have shown the SOSL return order is:

1. Case
2. Candidate__C
3. Contact
4. Lead

This allows you to cast your results to SObjects which have been stored in the `List<List<sObject>>` using indexing (`[]`).

Now that you have collections of known `SObject` type, you need to perform DML operations specific to that collection.

```
    ...
    
    Case[] cases = (Case[])Sobj[0];
    Candidate__C[] cand = (Candidate__C[])Sobj[1];
    Contact[] cont = (Contact[])Sobj[2];
    Lead[] leads = (Lead[])Sobj[3];
    for(Case Casse : Cases)        
    {
        Casse.SuppliedEmail= emailid;
    }
    for(Candidate__C Candi : cand)
    {
        Candi.Email_Id__C = emailid;
    }
    For(Contact con : Cont)
    {
        con.Email = emailid;
    }

    update cases;
    update cand;
    update cont;
    update leads;

    return Sobj;
    
    ...
```

In your original code, the `return` statement is before the attempted DML which would never have been reached. In saying this, you should also have been faced with a compile time `Single DML calls to each collection of SObject type` error.

For a single DML call to a grouped collection of `SObject` types you can use the `addAll()` method from the [List](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_list.htm) class.

```
    ...

    Case[] cases = (Case[])Sobj[0];
    Candidate__C[] cand = (Candidate__C[])Sobj[1];
    Contact[] cont = (Contact[])Sobj[2];
    Lead[] leads = (Lead[])Sobj[3];
    for(Case Casse : Cases)        
    {
        Casse.SuppliedEmail= emailid;
    }
    for(Candidate__C Candi : cand)
    {
        Candi.Email_Id__C = emailid;
    }
    For(Contact con : Cont)
    {
        con.Email = emailid;
    }

    List<SObject> groupedSobjects = new List<SObject>();
    groupedSobjects.addAll(cases);
    groupedSobjects.addAll(cand);
    groupedSobjects.addAll(cont);
    groupedSobjects.addAll(leads);
    update groupedSobjects;

    return Sobj;

    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update them all in a single transaction, just add them all in a list of SObjects.

```
List<SObject> updateSobjects = new List<SObject>();
updateSobjects.addAll(cases);
updateSobjects.addAll(cand);
updateSobjects.addAll(cont);
updateSobjects.addAll(leads);
update updateSobjects;
```

I just noticed that you are searching and updating the same email address in those records, it will not update anything except the `LastModifiedDate` on the records, just take care of that.